# Errors when Taxonomy is chosen in node's Term Reference field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have created a vocabulary called "Recipes" with several terms underneath (Appetizers, Dinner, etc). I also have a content type called "Recipe" with a Term Reference field for the Recipes vocabulary.

When a term (let's say Appetizers) does not yet have a node referencing it via that Term Reference field, the term's page shows up fine (albeit without any node content). However, when I choose one of those terms on a Recipe node via that Term Reference field, the term's page shows three error messages and various elements of the page (such as the footer and the nav bar) are not displayed. The errors are:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in _node_extract_type()
> (line 379 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/node/node.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in node_build_content() (line 1417 of /home/mysite/public_html/modules/node/node.module).
>
> EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7721 of
> /home/mysite/public_html/includes/common.inc).

I upgraded from 7.24 to 7.26, but that did not fix the issue. Google has not been particularly helpful. Does anyone here have any feedback on what might cause this issue? FYI, I also added a Term Reference field for the built-in "Tags" vocabulary, and the same issues occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This **EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node** errors seems to rear its ugly head in a lot of different contexts.

In my case it was a configuration of the view that showed the related nodes that had a couple of filters set wrong.

I had a relationship to related articles, but then in the filter section, Relationship was set to "Do not use a relationship" instead of using the related article. Setting the correct setting on the filter fixed the issue.